# How can I make this code to work with the Integer- > Int type signature?

Tags: haskell, types, signature

This code is working with the Int- > [Int] type signature, but I have to solve it with Integer -> [Int] type signature. What do I have to change to make it work?

```
toBin :: Int -> [Int]
toBin n 
    | n == 0 = []
toBin n  =   [n `mod` 2] ++ toBin (n `div` 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert an `Integer` (or any `Integral` type) to an `Int` (or any `Num` type):

```
toBin :: Integer -> [Int]
toBin 0 = []
toBin n = [fromIntegral (n `mod` 2)] ++ toBin (n `div` 2)
```

If `n` is an `Integer`, than `` n `mod` `2 `` is an `Integer` as well. We can not use `` n `mod` 2 `` as element of a list, since the return type is `[Int]`, so a list of `Int`s. We thus need to convert the `Integer` to an `Int` such that the type of the elements is correct, and we can convert an `Integer` to the corresponding `Int` (given the `Integer` can be represented by an `Int`) with `fromIntegral`.

Comment: Yes, but in this context it should definitely be discussed a bit (_pun not intended_) why this conversion is actually appropriate and why it should be done in that spot.